# MUI X Charts tooltip: Hide mark element

Tags: mui-x, mui-x-charts

[Screenshot from MUIX Docs showing tooltip with mark element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rjnW.png)

Trying to hide the mark element in the MUI X Charts tooltip (colored dot meant to delineate which dataset is being displayed) as described here: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/11150 - Maintainer describes how to pass along overrides via ThemeProvider but unfortunately I can't go that route with my project. Maintainer also points out that since the tooltip is appended to the end of the DOM when rendered, its tricky to target it.

Targeting via `sx` on the root chart element like so doesn't work either:

```
 sx={{
       "& .MuiChartsTooltip-mark": {
           display: "none",
        }
}}
```

I also tried targeting the `.MuiChartsTooltip-mark` class by adding a css rule to my parent wrapper component, no dice.

TIA for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Fix (doesn't work w/TS today- see https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/12254):

```
slotProps={{
        popper: {
          sx: {
            ["& .MuiChartsTooltip-mark"]: {
              display: "none",
            },
          },
        },
      }}
```